# Akka: issue with Timer

Tags: scala, akka, actor, akka-typed

I'm trying to create actor, which perform some action on timer. So I seek a way to schedule actor messages to self.

For this aim I use Behaviors.withTimers

```
object Consumer {
     sealed trait Command
     private object Timeout extends Command
     private case object TimerKey

     def apply(): Behavior[Command] = {
            Behaviors.withTimers(timers => new Consumer(timers).idle())
     }
  }
```

Method idle() must start sending messages Timeout to self in regular intervals.

```
  class Consumer(timers: TimerScheduler[Command]) {

       private def idle(): Behavior[Command] = {
           timers.startTimerWithFixedDelay(TimerKey, Timeout, FiniteDuration.apply(1, SECONDS))
           action()
           Behaviors.same
       }

       def action(): Behavior[Command] = {
             Behaviors.receiveMessage[Command] {
                case Timeout => println(" Consumer action done")
                Behaviors.same
         }
      }
    }
```

And action() must hook this messages against Behavior[Command]. But this is not happening. For some reasons, as I understand, timers not started. But what are that reasons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timers *are* being started and the `Timeout` message is being sent, but your `Consumer` actor isn't handling it, so the `println` never executes.

Your `apply` injects `timers` into `Consumer`.  In `idle`, you're starting the timer, then calling `action` to construct a new `Behavior`, but you then throw it away and actually use the `same` behavior your actor has (which won't respond to any messages).

`idle` should probably be defined along these lines (I'm also using the duration DSL: `import scala.concurrent.duration._`)

```scala
timers.startTimerWithFixedDelay(TimerKey, Timeout, 1.second)
action()
```

Comment: Yes, it is a solution: I remove Behaviors.same and invoke idle() from action()-method.